# ANTLR v4 plugin for Intellij IDEA: have to restart IJ after changing lexer grammar

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, antlr, antlr4

I try to use an ANTLR plugin for IJ, but there is an annoying problem. I don't  know, what I'm doing wrong, but after changing something in lexer grammar besides generating ANTLR recognizer (often, but not always) I have to restart IJ to see the correct parsing tree. Already tried to "Save all" or "Synchronize" before testing parser, but nothing helps. Has anyone encountered such a problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this related: https://github.com/antlr/intellij-plugin-v4/issues/242?

Comment: @glitch I think yes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As [glytching](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8200937/glytching) suggested in their comment, this is the problem described in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/antlr/intellij-plugin-v4/issues/242

The solution seems to be to hit Save. Another user also mentions touching the file from the terminal.

This puzzled me, as I'm using PyCharm and the way it seems to be set up by default is to auto-save as you work so I basically never interact with Save explicitly in any way. However, in this case hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> does seem to make a difference (compared with just letting it auto-save) and it solves the issue for me.

---

For clarity, my situation is:

- I have a grammar broken up into several parts (mixture of lexer, parser and combined grammars) which are imported into the 'main' grammar.
- I am working interactively with the ANTLR Preview window (OP mentioned generating a recognizer, but I think this issue is completely independent of running the Antlr generator).
- If I make a change in one of the imported grammars and switch back to the main grammar to re-run my start rule there it doesn't always pick up the change from the imported grammar.
- Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> after making the change in the imported grammar, before switching back to my main grammar, fixes the problem.